# pip for pre-installed Python and ones from Python.org

Tags: python, pip, osx-yosemite

OS: Yosemite 10.10.5

pre-installed
-2.7.10

from Python.org
-3.4
-3.5
(in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/)

I wanted to use pip for each of them, so I just looked for instructions.
Pip is already included in 2.7+ and 3.4+, right? 
But when I tried to use it in Terminal it said "command not found"

Then I found this which tells me what to do. When I executed `sudo easy_install pip` in Terminal, 
it gave me the following

```
...
Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip Finished processing dependencies for pip
```

Does it mean pip has been installed only for the pre-installed Python?
If so, how can I install pip for the ones from Python.org?

PS
Thank you in advance, actually this is my first question to post here, 
so I really appreciate any dos and don't for using Stack Overflow from predecessors:)

Comment: I kept on googling and found out that using get-pip.py may be helpful, and I executed it on Terminal and get `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages`, but still get `-bash: pip: command not found` when I execute"pip"...

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem by myself, not sure if this is helpful to others but I'm gonna share it.
It seems that pips are installed for each version of Python, so I needed to make sure that pip command is associated with the intended path. So:

1) I used easy_install-3.5 which I somehow installed.

2) I deleted all the .bash files in my home directory, and created a new .bash_profile there.

3) I wrote the following in it

```
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

given the directory has the pip, it works!